# Why does Windows think my phone has 52 GiB of internal disk space whereas my phone sees 64 GB?

Tags: internal-storage, windows, android-10

From my phone:

[image]

From Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate:

[image]

[image]

Comment: because Android is wrong. it mixes up phone storage (64 GiB) with Internal Storage (52 GiB)

Comment: The phone flash storage is divided into several partitions. One partition is read-only and reserved for Android OS itself and other system data. On Windows you only see the user data partition where apps and app data is stored on. And this partition is smaller than the full flash chip as the other space is occupied by the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your phone is showing you the total amount of storage inside your device.  This includes a [bunch of partitions](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/partitions) containing the operating system, radio image, preloaded apps, bootloader, recovery, etc.  These partitions are read-only, and many aren't even accessible within the Android OS, so they aren't exposed when connected to Windows—there wouldn't be any way to say "actually there's more space but you can't use it."  What Windows sees is the user-accessible space it can read from and write to, which is smaller than the total storage in the device.